# Who is the mathematician (and what is the book) who wrote of his cognitive decline in old age?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

EDIT:  Solved

There's a famous mathematician, who, in his later years, wrote a book about the wonderfulness of mathematics.

But in the introduction (I think) he lamented the fact that he was old and could no longer do groundbreaking math research.  He said that the job of mathematicians was to do *math*.  And now that he was writing a kind of pop book, he felt sad about it.

Who was this guy?  Anyone remember?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something I remember reading in "A Mathematician's Apology" by G. H. Hardy. I could be wrong because I read the book last about 10 years ago. He definitely talks about the contempt that "one who does" has for "one who teaches"

Comment: @Spencer That's the one!  Thank you very much!

Comment: "It is a melancholy experience for a professional mathematician to
find himself writing about mathematics. The function of a
mathematician is to do something, to prove new theorems, to add
to mathematics, and not to talk about what he or other mathematicians have done."  -G.H. Hardy